# Как сконфигурировать клиент AWS SDK для работы с Yandex облаком?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, яндекс-облако

В общем, на сайте яндекса написано, что их API полностью совместим с амазонском и => все либы должны работать.

Я скачал `AWSSDK.S3` и немного не понимаю, как сконфигурировать клиент для работы.

Как я понял в `AmazonS3Config` в поле ServiceURL я должен прописать что-то типа `http://s3.yandexcloud.net`.

А вот как я могу задать конечную точку региона от яндекса? Вроде, их клиент принимает только определенный тип у которого закрыт конструктор...

Возможно есть еще нюансы до которых я не дошел...

В [Java SDK](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/storage/tools/aws-sdk-java) такая возможность есть задать свою точку...

Comment: Ну как бы [исходники](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/) то есть. Можно заглянуть, как там и что работает.

Comment: @aepot эт да... Но вопрос, в том можно ли без хаканья заставить работать с яндексом...

Comment: [Вот что нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56038508/12888024), но можно еще нагуглить по ключевым словам "C# awssdk s3 custom endpoint"

Comment: @aepot работает, спасиб.